# Converting to arrayformula with vlookup goes wrong

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have a working formula here:

```
=IF(ISTEXT($D3);
IF(VLOOKUP($D3;klanten;15;FALSE)>15;
REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(" ";ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP($D3;klanten;
{6\5\3\4};FALSE)));"\s{2,}";" ");
REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(" ";
ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP($D3;klanten;{2\4};FALSE)));"\s{2,}";" "));"")
```

I copy and paste it down and that works.

But I want to wrap an arrayformula around it, so I did this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISTEXT($D3:D);
IF(VLOOKUP($D3:D;klanten;15;FALSE)>15;
REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(" ";VLOOKUP($D3:D;klanten;
{6\5\3\4};FALSE));"\s{2,}";" ");
REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(" ";
VLOOKUP($D3:D;klanten;{2\4};FALSE));"\s{2,}";" "));""))
```

Now my result is `#N/A` and the error is (when I point at the cell)

> The value '' was not found in the VLOOKUP evaluation.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: here is a copy and stripped version of my sheet:
[Copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FQNQORZM_muqNcDnXSKtMRQBdAsI3oPpNKiU-gCHwzo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: See main post, I added a copy of my sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISTEXT(D2:D);
 IFERROR(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D; klanten; 15; 0))>15;
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D; klanten; {6\ 5\ 3\ 4}; 0));
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D; klanten; {2\ 4}; 0)))); )); ; 999^99))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again, it works, and the code is much cleaner for me :-)